# ElephantBird doesn't work with AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-pig, emr, elephantbird

I'm trying to run a Pig script along with ElephantBird within AWS EMR. I'm using Hadoop 2.x to do that but I get the following message:

2014-09-09 14:53:11,001 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
2014-09-09 14:53:11,029 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new compressor [.snappy]
2014-09-09 14:53:11,040 FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Error running child : java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Counter, but class was expected
    at com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.util.PigCounterHelper.incrCounter(PigCounterHelper.java:55)
    at com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.LzoBaseLoadFunc.incrCounter(LzoBaseLoadFunc.java:70)
    at com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader.getNext(JsonLoader.java:128)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigRecordReader.nextKeyValue(PigRecordReader.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:544)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:775)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)

I've tried with different versions of elephant bird (from 3.0.9 to 4.0.x) but none of them seems to work. I degraded my cluster to Hadoop 1.x and I had no problem using elephant bird.
Any idea?

Comment: Any progress? I may be having the same issue right now.

Comment: Hi dranxo, unfortunately none. I finally used Hadoop 1.x on my EMR cluster and things were ok.